# How do i port forward in iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, iptables

I have created a new interface eth0:1 and assigned IP address using a DHCP server. Now, I want my applications to use the internet of this new interface created. 
I am doing this because in our Institute, we have a bandwidth limit on each IP address.

Now, I want to do something like:

If I try to use localhost:3129 as a proxy, this traffic gets forwarded to eth0:1 interface. How can I do so?

So that by using localhost:3129, i can actually use my interface eth0:1..
I only figured out this method because not many applications today have an option of binding to a particular interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3129 -d 1.2.3.4 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

But your statement that "not many applications today have an option of binding to a particular interface" does not match with my experience -- most applications I have deployed have an option to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some links that might be able to help out your request.

http://www.hackorama.com/network/portfwd.shtml
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/73
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-networking/30261-iptables-port-forwarding.html

Hope this helps!